# how to load a hyperlink in spesific div on page

Tags: css, layout

Hi guys I know I asked it on my other question but I didn't know how to explain my self

so in flexi css i made a template for my site it has a DIV Class ....

so if you look at the picture i provided,I want the link to open only in the Main column. Because now when I click on the link the entire page changes, but what I want only the main page to change.
I want the link to open in class='row_6 cssLI PageLayout28_row_6_design'
Please help

link to my image
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHvLV.png)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="includes/CSSLayouts/CSSLayouts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/CSSLayouts/debug_plus.js"></script>
<link href="includes/CSSLayouts/PageLayout28.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="includes/CSSLayouts/PageLayout28_user.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body class="PageLayout28_body_design">
<div class="PageLayout28">
<!-- (CSSLayouts Begin)  #PageLayout28 #build_version=1.1.284;pack=User;category=My Page Layouts;layout=;layoutType=page;scheme=;cssSource=file;assets=;halign=center;minwidth=1028px;maxwidth=1028px;width=1028px;bc=My Page Layouts;bl=final10062012-->

<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_wrapper_layout'>
<div class='wrapper cssLI PageLayout28_wrapper_design'>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_row_1_layout'>
<div class='row_1 cssLI PageLayout28_row_1_design'>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_column_3_layout'>
<div class='column_3 cssLI PageLayout28_column_3_design'><!-- column_3 Content Starts Here -->&nbsp;<!-- column_3 Content Ends Here -->
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_column_4_layout'>
<div class='column_4 cssLI PageLayout28_column_4_design'><!-- column_4 Content Starts Here -->&nbsp;<!-- column_4 Content Ends Here -->
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLClearC'></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_row_2_layout'>
<div class='row_2 cssLI PageLayout28_row_2_design'><!-- row_2 Content Starts Here -->&nbsp;<!-- row_2 Content Ends Here -->
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_row_3_layout'>
<div class='row_3 cssLI PageLayout28_row_3_design'>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_column_1_layout'>
<div class='column_1 cssLI PageLayout28_column_1_design'><!-- column_1 Content Starts Here -->&nbsp;<!-- column_1 Content Ends Here -->
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_column_2_layout'>
<div class='column_2 cssLI PageLayout28_column_2_design'>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_row_6_layout'>
<div class='row_6 cssLI PageLayout28_row_6_design'><!-- row_6 Content Starts Here -->

              MAIN

            <!-- row_6 Content Ends Here -->
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_row_7_layout'>
<div class='row_7 cssLI PageLayout28_row_7_design'>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_row_7_xtdalignwrapper_layout'>
<div class='row_7_xtdalignwrapper cssLI PageLayout28_row_7_xtdalignwrapper_design'>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_column_5_layout'>
                                               <div class='column_5 cssLI PageLayout28_column_5_design'><!-- column_5 Content Starts Here -->&nbsp;<!-- column_5 Content Ends Here -->
                                               </div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_column_6_layout'>
                                               <div class='column_6 cssLI PageLayout28_column_6_design'><!-- column_6 Content Starts Here -->&nbsp;<!-- column_6 Content Ends Here -->
                                               </div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_column_7_layout'>
                                               <div class='column_7 cssLI PageLayout28_column_7_design'><!-- column_7 Content Starts Here -->&nbsp;<!-- column_7 Content Ends Here -->
                                               </div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_column_8_layout'>
                                               <div class='column_8 cssLI PageLayout28_column_8_design'><!-- column_8 Content Starts Here -->&nbsp;<!-- column_8 Content Ends Here -->
                                               </div>
</div>
<div class='cssLClearC'>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLClearR'>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLClearR'></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLClearC'></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_row_4_layout'>
<div class='row_4 cssLI PageLayout28_row_4_design'><!-- row_4 Content Starts Here -->&nbsp;<!-- row_4 Content Ends Here -->
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_row_5_layout'>
<div class='row_5 cssLI PageLayout28_row_5_design'>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_column_9_layout'>
<div class='column_9 cssLI PageLayout28_column_9_design'><!-- column_9 Content Starts Here -->



<!-- column_9 Content Ends Here -->
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_column_10_layout'>
<div class='column_10 cssLI PageLayout28_column_10_design'><!-- column_10 Content Starts Here -->

          test | test | test | test |test

<!-- column_10 Content Ends Here -->
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLClearC'>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLO PageLayout28_row_8_layout'>
<div class='row_8 cssLI PageLayout28_row_8_design'><!-- row_8 Content Starts Here -->

      CopyRight © 2012   All rights reserved

<!-- row_8 Content Ends Here -->
</div>
</div>
<div class='cssLClearR'></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cssLClearL"></div>
<!-- #PageLayout28 (CSSLayouts End) -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to use iframes.  I have no idea what flexi layout editor is, but here's a link for you to learn more about them http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: You've got no idea what it is because you neglected to highlight it with your mouse, right-click and select Search Google for 'flexi layout editor' (It's a DreamWeaver extension) :p

Answer (score 2):

I think you want dynamic contains in main section without loading page,
   You can achieve this by using either i-frame or JavaScript/ jQuery toggle on based on your cantaint

here is jsfiddle example of it using **i-frame**

i tried make layout as per your flexi layout

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tushar234/EQqzy/)

Comment: do you have a demo for the Jquery ? i just dont want to use Iframe